# C++: Segmentation fault when separating header and implementation file (.hpp/.cpp)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

For a simple game I have this class, that checks if there are any objects in front of a game entity.

```
class FieldOfView : public anax::System<FieldOfView>
{
public:
    FieldOfView() :
    Base(anax::ComponentFilter().requires<components::Transform, components::FieldOfView>())
    {
    }

    void update()
    {
        using std::find;
        using std::begin;
        using std::end;
        using std::remove_if;

        auto& bus = Game::get().getMessageBus();

        for (auto& entity : getEntities())
        {
            auto collisions = getCollisions(entity);
            auto& inSight = entity.getComponent<components::FieldOfView>().inSight;

            for (auto& collided : collisions)
            {
                if (find(begin(inSight), end(inSight), collided) == end(inSight))
                {
                    inSight.push_back(collided);
                    bus.send<message::EntityEnteredFov>(entity, collided);
                }
            }

            std::function<bool(const anax::Entity&)> hasCollided = [&collisions](const anax::Entity& x) -> bool {
                return find(begin(collisions), end(collisions), x) != end(collisions);
            };

            for (const auto& seenEntity : inSight)
            {
                if ( !hasCollided(seenEntity) )
                    bus.send<message::EntityLeftFov>(entity, seenEntity);
            }

            inSight.erase(remove_if(begin(inSight), end(inSight), std::not1(hasCollided)), end(inSight));
        }
    }
};
```

This class is located in the file "FieldOfView.hpp". It works just expected. However, I want to separate header and implementation file, so I created a "FieldOfView.cpp".

```
void FieldOfView::update()
{
    // the same code as above
}
```

I also updated the header file ("FieldOfView.hpp"):

```
class FieldOfView : public anax::System<FieldOfView>
{
public:
    FieldOfView() :
    Base(anax::ComponentFilter().requires<components::Transform, components::FieldOfView>())
    {
    }

    void update();
};
```

When this code (hpp + cpp) is run, the program aborts because of an segmentation fault (`Segmentation fault: 11`). The error occurs in this line:

```
bus.send<message::EntityLeftFov>(entity, seenEntity);
```

When I compile and run the code using just the single hpp (no cpp file) everything is fine, there is no segmentation fault or any other kind of error. I have no idea what is causing this behavior…

Comment: Guess, you have a problem somewhere else in your code. Check for buffer overruns and memory usage

Answer (score 0):

Old, but: Does `bus` refer to a static member of `Game`? It seems to. If that is the case, you will be liable to the "[static initialisation order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html)" whereby different .cpp files might instantiate their own static variables, out of order compared to other objects that are trying to access them, possibly before they're ready.

Source: It just happened to me. I had a static const set of data, and a static container of pointers to that data. Defining these in different translation units led to a vague segfault, which I understand in principle but won't waste time trying to figure out the exact mechanistic cause. So, I moved the offending instantiations into a single cpp file, put them in the right order of dependency, and all was well again.